# Laravel Paginator object does not have render method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I do the following:

```
$array = new LengthAwarePaginator(array_slice($array, $offset, $perPage, true), count($array),$perPage, $page, ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);
dd($array->render());
```

and i get the proper html output of the render method.

Then I try:

```
$array =  new Paginator(array_slice($array, $offset, $perPage, true), $perPage, $page, ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);
dd($array->render());
```

and the output is "".

When I `(dd($array));` I get :

```
Paginator {#310 ▼
  #hasMore: false
  #items: Collection {#315 ▶}
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "https://localhost/search/3"
  #query: array:1 [▶]
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Anyone know why my Paginator doesn't have a render method?

Comment: What Laravel 5 version are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson I'm using 5.2.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of a misunderstanding in the way Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator works. For the this object you cannot pass in an array of size $perPage like you do with a LengthAwarePaginator because this Paginator would then not know whether there is a next page or not. So, the solution that I came up with (although I have not found any docs which mention this) is to pass in `array_slice($array, $offset, $perPage * 2, true)` as input to the Paginator. This way it always knows whether there are more and I still don't need to know how many total items there are.